# RewriteRule .htaccess is forwarding PHP Variable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to forward old posts on my site using .htaccess RewriteRule to new addresses.

First rule is

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=16
RewriteRule ^current_article\.php$ /article/basics-of-electrosurgery [L,R=301]
```

which rewrites http://www.megadyne.com/current_article.php?id=16
to http://www.megadyne.com/article/basics-of-electrosurgery

Second rule is

```
RewriteRule ^article/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ articles.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

which rewrites http://www.megadyne.com/article/basics-of-electrosurgery to http://www.megadyne.com/articles.php?id=basics-of-electrosurgery

All works fine except the final result is http://www.megadyne.com/article/basics-of-electrosurgery?id=16 and I don't want it to append the final variable "?id=16" to the address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `?` at the end of your first rule, and should probably add some boundaries to the query string match:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=16($|&)
RewriteRule ^current_article\.php$ /article/basics-of-electrosurgery? [L,R=301]
```

When there's a query string in the request, it automatically gets appended to the end of the rule's target unless you are creating a query string in the target. So here, you're creating an empty query string, and without the `QSA` flag, the existing query string won't get appended.

Comment: Here is my new code: 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=16($|&) 
RewriteRule ^current_article\.php$ /article/basics-of-electrosurgery? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^article/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ articles.php?id=$1 [NC]

But it still is including the ID variable...

Comment: @BrianBarrus did you clear your browser's cache? 301 redirects are permanent so the browser caches those.